# CGFontCreateWithDataProvider freezes unit test

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, custom-font

I have unit test to check if font is registered from file. When CGFontCreateWithDataProvider is called, the test freezes (I've added breakpoint and when I step over the breakpoint is unattached and test the logic is not continued). Any advice? When I run app, this method works perfectly.

Thank you,

```
CFErrorRef fonterror;
NSURL * fonturl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalFolder];
CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fonturl);
// break point    
CGFontRef newFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
// never continued.
if (newFont) {
    if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(newFont, &fonterror)) {
        CGFontRelease(newFont);
        ...
} else ...
} else ...
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not at all :( I've removed the test

Comment: I eventually narrowed it down to my exceptions breakpoint in Xcode. It was set to "All Exceptions". Editing the breakpoint and setting it to "All Objective-C Exceptions" solved the issue for me. Good luck!